# Forcing users to grab new site content, not use cache

Tags: html, browser-cache

We just rolled out a completely new website, with a lot of the old images gone.  We have been swamped by called from clients this morning because they can't get access to the sites content because they are still using cache on the page.  Is there a way using the meta tags or something that will force them not to use the cache content?  This will just be temporary for a week, then we will remove it, just so our users have the latest site up.  Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I request that browsers always update (a.k.a. never cache) certain page elements, such as CSS sheets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932195/how-can-i-request-that-browsers-always-update-a-k-a-never-cache-certain-page-e)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not change the HTML source to show a different URL to the images and resources so the browser is forced to download a new version. This technique is used a lot to invalidate the browsers cache. Here is an example:

```
<img src="/logo.jpg?version=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css?version=1">
```

Comment: This is the method I would recommend, we use this on any static files, as the cache varies by the full url, so a querystring parameter will result in the same file server-side, but a new item in cache.

Comment: We would have done that, but its the style sheet that is the issue.  We switched from a static image, to a div tag with a background image.  Sorry, I should have been clear.  Would doing this with the style sheet solve the problem?

Comment: The same concept can be applied to styles. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```

Indicates cached information should not be used and instead requests should be forwarded to the origin server.